# aiogram, доступ к глобальным данным в отдельных роутерах и хэндлерах

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, aiogram-3.x

я пишу бот на aiogram 3 и python

При запуске я загружаю в память (в глобальные словари) некоторый объем данных из файлов (размер каждого порядка 10 мб), который затем нужен будет в большинстве хэндлеров бота

Пока у меня бот и хэндлеры были все в одном файле, я просто использовал в хэндлерах глобальные переменные dict1, dict2, etc

Поскольку у бота очень много разных команд и соответственно, хэндлеров тоже много, решил структурировать их по роутерам в разные файлы, аналогично описанному в данной статье: https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/routers/

Как наиболее грамотно использовать загруженное в память при старте бота содержимое в разных хэндлерах, которые теперь распределены по роутерам в разных файлах?